# Prevent reboot loop from critical error in win7

Tags: windows-7, reboot

My machine is stuck rebooting after displaying an error dialog stating that a critical error has occoured and that it will shutdown within a minute. This started happening right after MS Essentials found a trojan. The machine will reboot whether or not I login.

I'm guessing that this error will go away if I can update the AV software and remove the virus but 1 minute is too short a time frame to accomplish this in =)

So I have tried to prevent windows from booting, without success. What I have tried so far is

1. F8 - Disable reboot on system failures
2. shutdown /a *(only gives me a nice 1115 err)*
3. Control Panel-> System-> Recovery-> Settings-> Untick reboot at system failure

Any pointers as to how to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Critical" Windows executables include `winlogon.exe`, `lsass.exe`, and `csrss.exe`.  I think you get this message if one of those crashes or terminates for some reason, which could happen if a trojan has modified them.  Could also indicate an issue with a DLL imported by them (there are quite a few).

If you have a known working system, you may try booting your infected system off of a WinPE boot disk and replacing the files.  However, honestly, you're probably looking at a reinstall.

Comment: I did a recovery from a known working system as recommended. The forced reboot is gone. Virus is left but was now easy to remove. Added all WinUpdates and now running a full scan... so far so good, thx!

Answer (score 1):

If it appears a shutdown dialogue try run this:

`shutdown -a`

Or try to boot in `safe mode`, from there you can install antivirus and scan your system.

Comment: Tried that (see step 2 above) but it did not work.

Comment: Try safe mode then.

Comment: Safe mode rebooted as well I'm afraid =/

Comment: Ok! Maybe your windows really needs to be changed. Try reinstall it, if you can't maybe there is something with your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be worrying too much, download this onto a cd or usb key and boot the machine and boot from usb or cd and run through the wizard to clean up the pc.

Then

boot the Windows and do a Repair, once you have that done reboot into safe mode with network and get one of the many scanners from the web to check your system is tiptop.